# select and option AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I would like to put this code in select / option model.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:100%">MONTHS
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="color: black;text-align: center;">
        <li ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'month'" ng-click="vm.cellIsOpen = false">Month</li>
        <li ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'week'" ng-click="vm.cellIsOpen = false">Week</li>
        <li ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'day'" ng-click="vm.cellIsOpen = false">Day</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried with value, ng-change but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
<select ng-model="vm.calendarView"
    ng-options="option in ['month', 'week', 'day']">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
<select ng-model="vm.calendarView">
     <option value="false">Month</option>
     <option value="false">week</option>
     <option value="false">Day</option>
</select>
```